# Using accelerator table without menuitem

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxpython desktop application and I am using python 2.7 and wxpython 2.8.

I know how to add an accelerator table to a menuitem but I would like to fire an event when a user press a certain combination of keys without having a menuitem.
The user could have the focus on any field in my UI but when he press (for instance) CTRL-L an event should be fired. How to do this ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always need to bind your accelerator table items to `wx.EVT_MENU`, but wxPython doesn't require that you use a menu item object. Here's a simple example:

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tutorial", size=(500,500))

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        randomId = wx.NewId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onKeyCombo, id=randomId)
        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('Q'), randomId )])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

        text = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        text.SetFocus()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onKeyCombo(self, event):
        """"""
        print "You pressed CTRL+Q!"

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

In this example, we just create a random id, bind that id to an event handler and then create an accelerator that will fire that handler, which in this case is CTRL+Q. To make things more interesting, I added a text control widget and set the focus to that. Then if you press CTRL+Q, you should see the event handler fire and some text appear in your console window.

You can read more about accelerators here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/

Comment: Thanks Mike, what if I need to catch ENTER key. I mean, I have a data entry form in a panel, when user press ENTER I would like to intercept it and start an event. Do I have to add the binding to every textctrl (in a recursive way) or the are other ways ?

Comment: It depends on when you want to catch it. If you want to catch ENTER after the user finishes filling out a text control, then you'll want to catch it there. If you want to catch it globally, then you will have to attach it to all text controls and any special widgets, like Text controls and grids.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, any thoughts on how to do this now that wx.NewId() is being deprecated?  https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.functions.html#wx.NewId

Comment: It looks like you *can* just use arbitrary ids, i.e. `randomId = self.panel.GetId()`.  Not sure this is a great idea, but it does seem to work.

Comment: I use `wx.NewId()`, which is guaranteed not to conflict with any common ids nor any in-use ids